# Woocommerce align prices and texts

Tags: css, text

Is it possible to align prices and product titles in grid view.
If i have a product with one line title I want its price to go lower so it aligns with the price of the 2 or more line product title.

I hope I was clear 
I am appending an image
[image]

thank you

Comment: this is an html/css question that is not specific to wordpress

Answer (score 1):

solution 1. why don't you increase some width 4th image container ..
solution 2. put one 
 and   tags after product name so it will create some space ... but if your theme is mobile friendly then when you see on other monitors means on bigger than your monitors then it looks weird ...

Comment: if it worked then upvote me ...